# Using C macro variable in #include

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have C code file containing the following include:

```
#include MYHEADER
```

I know such include using variable is a bad practice but it is not my code, I just want to compile it. I want `MYHEADER` variable to have `<some_header.h>` value, rather than `"some_header.h"`.
I have tried may ways to pass it, so far none of them worked.

E.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -DMYHEADER=<some.h> -o sample.o sample.c` does not work,
I always get error: `#include expects "FILENAME" or \<FILENAME\>`. Using ARM GCC compiler on Windows.

Please advise.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?  [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Chris It's not his own code.

Comment: This is not possible with the C preprocessor. I suspect the file is supposed to be updated using some other tool.

Comment: `#define MYHEADER <stdio.h>` ... `#include MYHEADER` compiles with MS VC. But `#define MYHEADER stdio.h` ... `#include <MYHEADER>` does not.

Comment: The TL;DR: _No_ (and I've tried many times ;-) Note that `"some_header.h"` works with the the `MYHEADER` trick. But, IIRC, `<some_header.h>` will _not_. But, the only difference is that `"some_header.h"` will scan the _current_ directory looking for `some_header.h` before doing what `<some_header.h>` will do: Look in `-I` directories, look in some "standard" directories (e.g. `/usr/include`). So, if there is _no_ `some_header.h` in the current directory (when compiling), there is _no_ difference.

Comment: Create a file `indirect_some_header.h` containing (just) `#include <some_header.h>` and then use `-DMYHEADER="indirect_some_header.h"` (with appropriate escapes for the quotes for your shell)

Comment: @Barmar: “This is not possible with the C preprocessor”: Yes, it is possible. C 2018 6.10.2 4 says “A preprocessing directive of the form `#` `#include` *pp-tokens* *new-line* (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing tokens after `include` in the directive are processed just as in normal text. (Each identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing tokens.)…”

Comment: Is your command-line processor treating `<` and `>` as file redirection? What happens if you put `-DMYHEADER=<some.h>` in quotes?

Comment: check your folder, there'll by a file named `-o`, and gcc would receive input from some probably non-existent `some.h` and ignore it

Comment: @phuclv: If `some.h` does not exist, the shell should report that as an error and not execute the command. They probably have `some.h` as a file in their directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you get is produced by GCC if `MYHEADER` is defined to be empty (there are no tokens in its replacement list). If the command-line processor (also called a shell) you are using takes `<some.h>` to indicate file redirection, with `<` indicating to take input from `some.h` and `>` taking the `-o` that follows it to indicate writing to `-o`, then it leaves `-DMYHEADER=` with an empty replacement list.

If so, a fix may be to quote the switch:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c "-DMYHEADER=<some.h>" -o sample.o sample.c
```

Here are two tests for this, in addition to trying the above command:

- Check whether your directory contains a file named `-o`. If so, it was created by the indirection, confirming that is what is happening.
- Create a file named `x.c`, put `MYHEADER` (and nothing else) in it, and execute `arm-none-eabi-gcc -E x.c -DMYHEADER=<some.h>`. If the command-line processor complains about no file name following `>`, that confirms the hypothesis. If it executes the command, or if it executes the command after you add, say, `foo` after the `>`, the output will reveal what `MYHEADER` is replaced with. (The `-E` switch requests preprocessing, so the single line containing `MYHEADER` will be replaced by a blank line if `-DMYHEADER=` is passed to GCC.)

One problem with this hypothesis is the command-line processor should have complained it could not open `some.h` for the input redirection. But perhaps you have a file of that name in your directory, which would satisfy the command-line processor.

Another possibility is that the C standard does not fully specify how tokens resulting from macro replacement in an `#include` are processed. When `<name.h>` appears directly in an `#include`, it is processed by a special grammar token, an *h-char-sequence*. When macro replacement is used instead, the standard says, in C 2018 6.10.2 4:

> … The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a `<` and a `>` preprocessing token pair or a pair of `"` characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined.

I do not expect this is the problem, as a test on Compiler Explorer suggests GCC processes a replacement of `MYHEADER` with `<stdio.h>` in an ordinary suitable way.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I would not have figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `#define MYHEADER <some_header.h>` before the `#include MYHEADER` might work.
or
If you have many like this, you could put all the "#define"s in a file.txt and #include that file.txt before using the #inclue MYHEADER